# Typescript Allow class property to have multiple types

Tags: typescript

In Typescript I have two classes, Foo and Bar

```
export class Foo{
  data: Bar<Types>
}

export class Bar<T>{
  attributes: T
}
```

Next to that I also have a type

```
export type Types = Circle | Square
```

Next up I declare my variable

```
x: Bar<Circle>
```

But when I want to assign a value to this variable by doing

```
x = someRandonJsonData
```

I get the following type error:

```
Type 'Bar<Types>' is not assignable to type 'Bar<Circle>'.
```

I'm wondering where my mistake is in all of this ?

Comment: What is the type of `someRandonJsonData`. If it is `Bar<Types>` this error is expected.. and it's there for the same reason you can't assign a value of type `Types` to a variable of type `Circle`

Comment: It is indeed `Bar<Types>`. So how would I be able to make my `Bar` property attributes to either be `Circle` or `Square` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:

```
let x: Bar<Circle>;

let z: Bar<Types>;

x = z;
```

The problem is that `z` is a wider type, because it could be the equivalent of `Bar<Circle>` or `Bar<Square>` - and the latter is not compatible; so you need to narrow it with a type guard:

```
function isCircle(item: Bar<Types>): item is Bar<Circle> {
    return (item.attributes.hasOwnProperty('radius'));
}

if (isCircle(z)) {
    x = z;
}
```

Here's a full example:

```
interface Circle {
    radius: number;
}

interface Square {
    width: number;
}

type Types = Circle | Square

class Foo{
  data: Bar<Types>
}

class Bar<T>{
  attributes: T
}

let x: Bar<Circle> = {
    attributes: {
        radius: 4
    }
};

let y: Bar<Square> = {
    attributes: {
        width: 4
    }
};

let z: Bar<Types> = {
    attributes: {
        radius: 4
    }
};

// Error, as it may not be compatible
x = z;

function isCircle(item: Bar<Types>): item is Bar<Circle> {
    return (item.attributes.hasOwnProperty('radius'));
}

if (isCircle(z)) {
    // Works
    x = z;
}
```